# JQuery syntax error when selecting element of the same name

Tags: jquery

I want to select input with the same name, but get syntax error:

```
$("input[name=$(this).prop('name')]");
```

But I am able to get string by `$(this).prop('name')`.

**EDIT:**

Thank you for all your answers. I think they all work. But could anyone explain why the two plus sign at beginning and end make the jquery code parsed inside string? Reference will be appreciated, thanks

**EDIT2:**

I know plus sign is for string concatenation. But in this case, nothing is before the first + or after second +. So what are being concatenated here? Sorry if the question looks too naive

Answer (score 4):

It should be this:

```
$("input[name='"+$(this).prop('name')+"']");
```

jQuery doesn't parse jQuery code on strings. For it to be executed you should place the jQuery `prop()` function outside the string.

Comment: Are u missing single quotes around the name value? May be I am wrong

Comment: Could you explain why the two plus sign at beginning and end make the jquery code parsed inside string? Reference will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3):

> > *But could anyone explain why the two plus sign at beginning and end make the jquery code parsed inside string?*

Let's look at it  step by step.

First, let's take the original approach:

```
$("input[name=$(this).prop('name')]");
```

The function "$" (which is an alias for jQuery) will get called with a string argument:

```
"input[name=$(this).prop('name')]"
```

jQuery will parse this string and interpret it like this:

```
/* 
Okay, I need to find an <input> 
that has an attribute "name", 
and the value of that attribute has to be, literally, "$(this).prop('name')". 
So, I'm looking for something that looks like this: */

<input name="$(this).prop('name')" />
```

However, what you probably meant to find was more like this:

```
<input name="some name, actually" />
```

(and "some name, actually" would be in the name property of $this at the point where you are making the original call)

Let's look at the new approach now:

When you write

```
$("input[name=" + $(this).prop('name') + "]");
```

You are constructing part of the string from your JavaScript objects. You are taking $(this) (which is a jQuery object), call its function "prop" to retrieve a property called "name", and using the output of that function in the new query. So if $(this).prop('name') returns "AWESOME", you are asking jQuery to find something that looks like this:

```
<input name="AWESOME" />
```

This should be more like what you were looking for!

Comment: Thank you for elaboration. I understand every single word you say perfectly. Yet my question remains: why the two plus sign can do what they do? In other words, why the two plus signs make jquery parse variable inside a string? Is it a special syntax or something? I am not able to google any reference on that.

Comment: I know plus sign is for string concatenation. But in this case, nothing is before the first + or after second +. That makes me confused.

Comment: There's nothing special about it, this is very basic JavaScript. In the above, `$(this).prop('name')` gets executed and returns "AWESOME" which would then give you `$("input[name=AWESOME]")`. Note the double quite (") before and after the quote for string concatanation.

Comment: But we concatenate nothing here... nothing is before first + or after second +

Comment: The strings we concatenate are: "input[name]" (that's one), the result of the call to prop('name') (that's two), and "]" - that's three. Three strings are being contatenated.

Answer (score 2):

You're literally looking for an `input` element with the name `$(this).prop('name')`. What you want to do is write something like this:

```
$("input[name="+$(this).prop('name')+"]");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
$("input[name=" + $(this).prop('name') + "]");
```